# Адаптация linux команд под windows

Tags: c++, linux, c, ос, эмулятор

Хотелось спросить совета по тому, в правильном направлении я двигаюсь или нет. По предмету операционные системы дали задачу, написать программу адаптирующую команды linux (rm,tail,cd,ls,comm,cd) под windows (дословно, преподаватель сказал что бы они работали в windows как в linux). Собственно, возник вопрос, возможно ли скомпилить экземпляры утилит coreutils под windows, создать для них "окружение" что бы они "думали" что выполняются под linux (с соответствующими заглушками) и выполнять? Т.е моя программа будет неким аггрегатором доступных пользователю команд, которая воссоздает окружение linux, запускает файл команды, перенаправляет ей аргументы, и перенаправляет ее вывод в консоль windows. Про cygwin,mingw и эмуляторы терминала под windows знаю, не подходят по условию задачи.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста вопрос. Вам нужно скомпилировать unix-команды, чтобы они были исполняемыми файлами windows (как в cygwin) или запускать elf-файлы в windows (как делает wine, только наоборот)?

Comment: Раз уж тема С/С++ и Операционные системы, то логично было бы если задание звучало так: "Написать самостоятельно аналоги Linux программ rm,tail,cd,ls,comm для Windows"

Comment: Соберите `busybox` под Windows, там всё сразу в одном бинарнике.

Comment: Если Вам  надо просто исполнять bash на винде ,то вот. 
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10   

bash on windows



Если хотите сами ,может вам следует написать конвертор bash' a в batch.